I have to keep react-app-env.d.ts file Open in VS Code in order for my component to not say Cannot find module '../../assets/icon.png'
I have a react-app-env.d.ts file with a bunch of declarations to handle different image extension types. But as soon as I close this tab (in VS Code), my component where I am importing an icon, it complains that Cannot find module... so it seems that I need to leave the react-app-env.d.ts file open to avoid the Lint or VS Code error. This is so strange, im sure someone knows why
I thought **app-env.d.ts file would be sufficient for "Cannot find module..." error when importing icons
